# Existing UIDocument Won't Update On iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument

I have an app that has no problem creating, storing, moving, and reading new files to and from the Cloud.  What I'm having an issue with is modifying documents that already exist in the cloud.  I'm calling

```
[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES fromURL:localURL toURL:iCloudURL];
```

in both cases and can confirm that it fires and the destination/local URLs are correct.  For whatever reason though it won't edit a file, only create a new one.  My guess is that I need to do something different for file editing, but maybe I am missing something.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that succeeds in updating the document however I'm not sure if this is the optimal way.  I'm calling:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:iCloudURL]];
```

Before calling the [setUbiquitious] method.  Would love to see another solution though.